# Dry run - temporary repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, dependency-injection

Working on an MVC app, for process automation, using Event-Consumer pattern with StructureMap.

Due to the critical nature of some process, we would like to "dry run" them say 30 minutes before scheduled time.

I'm still exploring options, so please feel free to suggest if you've done it before.

This specific question is to ask whether it's recommended to mock the process by

- Copying data from the database into a mock IRepository
- Which then will be passed on to the consumers, so that all changes etc. will be saved in the mock repository
- Use the same mock repository for all consumers down the pipeline of the process
- At the end display the result of the dry-run, no production information is altered

**Clarification**
By "process automation" I mean there are a list of rules that the software will go through and follow to manipulate a set of data.

Obviously the data will be changed after applying those rules, e.g. say if for example in a energy retailer scenario, at end of every day you'd mark all invoices which haven't been paid pass due date as late and charge a fee.

Say if you'll have only one go at it and can't get it wrong, you would want to run the process to see if there was any errors

**Further thoughts**
So it seems not possible to copy all the needed data into the mock repository due to size and the complex business rules around the process, we are thinking of having the regular repository for read-only and another "mock" repository for any save/update/delete to the entities.

We're currently using NHiberate configured with Fluent connecting to a SQL Server db

Many thanks

Comment: You need to define what "for process automation" and "dry run" means in your case. It is very unclear what your problem is (i.e. why do you need "mock the process" and how "process" relates to database).

Comment: Hi Alexei, sorry I can't actually describe the exact process, as I'm working for a client and is bound by a NDA.

By "process automation" I mean there are a list of rules that the software will go through and follow to manipulate a set of data. 

Obviously the data will be changed after applying those rules, e.g. say if for example in a energy retailer scenario, at end of every day you'd mark all invoices which haven't been paid pass due date as late and charge a fee.

Say if you'll have only one go at it and can't get it wrong, you would want to run the process to see if there was any errors

Comment: I see - I have no experience with such large operations on DBs, so no answers from me. Note that "process" (at least on SO) is more commonly associated with "OS process/running executable", so it is the reason why I was confused. There is no reason to explain your particular case - simply asking how to simulate multiple related updates on DB without commit could give better results (assuming single transaction is not possible, also need to clarify if there are any DB triggers or code is purely client side...)